# 3-digit scores don't line up correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I would post a screenshot, but can't on mobile :-( 
And this sentence alone doesn't satisfy our quality standards, so I'm writing some more crap to improve the quality.

Seen here: [Why does adding 0.1 multiple times remain lossless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120311/why-does-adding-0-1-multiple-times-remain-lossless?newsletter=1&nlcode=44322%7cfd5b)

> [image: The score is messed up]

Comment: @nicael I know how to *take* it, but not how to post it easily.

Comment: No repro on iOS app so can't post screenshot on your behalf.

Comment: Posted a screenshot for you.

Comment: @hichris123 Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in the next update (for answer vote counts of any size, not just three) -- Thanks for the report!